# WebService Client - Replace Umlaut in class name

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, webservice-client, diacritics

I got a webservice description from an external source and have to build an interface with it.
This is not the problem, got it all working. Webservice Client is automatically generated using Eclipse and Axis.

But in that description I have something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Übersicht">
            ...
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see there is an Ü Umlaut in the element name.

When I'm generating the Webservice client in Eclipse, this will generate a Java class named `Type_Übersicht.java`. While this is not a problem for the compiler, it violates our code style rules. It is the only class in the whole workspace with a special char in it.

So, question:
Can I tell the Eclipse Webservice Generator to map given names or single characters into something else? Unfortunately changing the description is not an option...

Comment: Are you using CXF or AXIS?

Comment: @Ihuang: I'm using AXIS, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify generated classes either by using hints in the XSD or by using a binding file although I'm not familiar with getting binding files working with the eclipse generator (I usually use the maven plugin).
Try editing the XSD/WSDL like this

```
<xs:complexType name="Type">
 <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Übersicht">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:class name="Ubersicht"/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: @lhuang Nope, gives me a `PARSER_ERROR` because of `jaxb`

Comment: It seems that we couldn't do this with AXIS. Maybe you have to change the WSDL/XSD manually.

Comment: Yes, I'd personally use the WS import ant task or maven tasks after editing the WSDL manually. A binding file would allow you to not edit the WSDL directly if you prefer. This article suggests how this would be possible: http://www.soa.si/2011/09/30/developing-axis2-web-services-with-jax-b-data-binding-in-eclipse/

Comment: So in the end I changed the WSDL manually, because I guess the Umlaut shouldn't have been there anyways. But thanks for the link, I learned something new.